# What language should I use for editing documents?

Tags: html, css, latex, document, postscript

Document editors are nice but they have their limitations.
What is a good alternative to them?
I already know HTML and CSS and while they can do the job, they are ill-suited for printed documents.
I was thinking in learning LaTeX, because many scholars use it. But I wonder if someone would recommend another language such as postscript.

Comment: what kinds of document ?  The kind of document materially affects the suitability of one tool or another.

Comment: HTML & CSS work fine for printed documents, but they're verbose. You'll spend more time marking up than writing. Go with LaTeX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got a chance to write an [entire paper](https://github.com/timvisher/CMSCU498-Research-Paper/) in LaTeX for my final semester of College and found it to be easier than I thought it would be.  A couple of the nice things I found about it were

1. A fairly lightweight syntax for most things (tables being the only real offender, but no one can get text tables right).
2. An extremely wide array of syntax for doing anything from automatically marking up a chemical formula to writing inline lists.
3. Beautiful output automatically.
4. Extremely easy to write modular documents where I might store a chapter in a file and then simply `\include{}` it in another.  One particularly nice use I found for this was to include code that I had written in the document simply by referencing the files.
5. Wonderful support for footnotes and bibliographic references.
6. [Libraries](http://www.ctan.org/) for just about anything you can imagine.

The major drawbacks are, IMHO:

1. A lack of any real direction or life in the language.  It feels dead, and not because it's done.
2. A frustrating build process, although there are tools to help with that, from a simple [bash script](https://github.com/timvisher/CMSCU498-Research-Paper/blob/master/build.bash) to a full fledged [`make` file](http://xpt.sourceforge.net/tools/latexmake/).

If you're interested in learning LaTeX, I would recommend starting out by reading the [Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX 2e PDF](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf).

However, I decided against using LaTeX for most things that I write these days specifically because it feels dead and has a frustrating build process.  I instead switched over to [MultiMarkdown](http://fletcherpenney.net/multimarkdown/), as it is well supported and can be transformed into a large array of other formats, including LaTeX which can then be hand massaged if you really need to in order to get it the format expected by some publication.  If you haven't played with [MultiMarkdown](http://fletcherpenney.net/multimarkdown/) or [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) before, then I highly recommend checking them out.  The syntax is extremely lightweight and natural, even compared to LaTeX.  I find that except for some of the higher level typographical constructs, MultiMarkdown supports everything I need on a regular basis.

My 2 cents.

Comment: latexmk greatly assists in the build process

Comment: "Real direction or life in the language" I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: What I mean is that LaTeX doesn't feel like it's going anywhere anymore.  There are tons of efforts as far as evolving Markdown, for instance, to meet all sorts of needs because it's such a popular syntax.  LaTeX seems, at this point, to have thoroughly scratched the itch of everyone who uses it and so no real effort is being put forth for its development.

Answer (score 8):

LaTeX is fine. You don't want to write postscript by hand.

Comment: +1: this is probably the best option for 'high academic papers'.  Do remember to get the style files that the journals publish for their (prospective) authors to use.

Comment: @High `high` is a reference to your nickname, not an adjective for the papers

Comment: @XMLforDUmmies: hahahahahaha what a dummy I am !

Answer (score 2):

I’m using **LaTeX** almost exclusively nowadays, at least for text documents (everything from CV over letters to manuals).

For quick one-off notes, I’m actually using **Markdown** (without a renderer. I just think that Markdown preserves document structure quite nicely even when used in text-only mode).

For presentations and spreadsheets, I use appropriate applications, though. In particular, I don’t think LaTeX is that well-suited to do the former (depending on your style of presentations, obviously. Mine have next to no text though …).

Comment: Spreadsheets I'll give you (maybe, I haven't combed CTAN), but Beamer is an excellent way to make presentations. You get a PDF not a (version and font dependant) ppt(x) and you CAN still do incremental slides and even figures (with TikZ). No it isn't drag and drop, a quick one-off couple slides might be better in PPT, but for a high-quality presentation, give Beamer a go.

Comment: @Joel: like I said, depends on the presentations you do. I *have* used Beamer in the past, and with good results. But high-quality presentations for me (and most professionals) mean images, not text. Quoth Seth Godin: “No more than six words on a slide. EVER” Presentations are about delivering information in the most concise and aesthetically appealing way possible. Other applications support this **much** better than LaTeX. Of course the latter can be used but it’s simply not the best tool for the job.

Comment: (cont’d): Two points in particular: LaTeX/Beamer may produce beautiful results but doesn’t support the **process** of designing a slide deck at all. That process entails having a display of all your slides (the “light table”) with sketches of the final design, and rearranging them like a story board, until they tell your story. This is best done with graphical representations, and drag&drop (or actual paper slips). On a more technical subject, LaTeX in general has poor support for the free placement of elements (e.g. along a grid) which is often needed in slides.

Comment: I suppose it really does matter what you intend to do with it. As a physics grad student, I don't need many words, I need equations and graphs, and the story is usually set linearly, therefore Beamer is excellent for me. Certainly the process is harder with Beamer, but using it on conjuntion with TikZ might help you with fine placement. You can put graphics in nodes and then fine adjust the nodes. I would never dispute that Beamer is harder in some ways. The best thing is that I KNOW when I open my presentation on someone's computer my greek symbols will all be there and not little squares.

Comment: I totally agree with Joel here.  One answer to Konrad (and the way I did my own presentation) would be to include your slides in a compendium document that allows you to quickly move them around independently of one another.  That's what I found myself doing with the presentation I did in Beamer.  I called the file something descriptive of its content (best practice. ;) and then included them all in the master presentation file.  Then, I can move them around as I will and regenerate the PDF.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to do. If you are planning to write a formal document, maybe for printing too, just go for LaTex.

Not difficolt as it may appear at the very beginning but professional and fulfilling.

If Web is your goal, go for HTML / CSS.

OpenOffice or Word would do the trick in most cases; do not underestimate them, if you are going to use them (example for job) take time to learn them.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on zzzzBov's commmment, LaTeX is SUPPOSED to allow the writer to concentrate on the content and allow the compiler/documentclass to handle formatting (and that usually is true). If you use HTML/CSS to format you will probably be spending more time (rather than less) doing formatting. Imagine that the LaTeX documentclass is the CSS, only it is already written for you, and your LaTeX source is the content, only the tags are more functional (such as italics or equations) than for patching between the HTML and the CSS (`<div ...>`). I recommend the [LaTeX wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX) as an easy way to start, and the [short-math-guide](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf), it if you need mathematics. Enjoy!